# Evernote : Time note getting updated when object pushed, tags not included

Tags: java, evernote

I am working on integrating evernote functionality into my project. Currently, I am able to save the note, but when I add tags in the note objects, they are not getting updated on evernote side. Also, when I edit an Evernote note object, the timestamp wont be updated on evernote side. What am I doing wrong? No error log so far. Thank you..

Code :

```
 @Override
    public boolean pushNoteToEvernote(int groupNoteId) {
        System.out.println("Push note to evernote is called. ");
        GroupNotes groupNotes = this.groupNotesService.getGroupNoteById(groupNoteId);
        if (!(groupNotes == null)) {
            try {
                Person person = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
                if (person.isEvernoteConsumed()) {
                    EverNote everNote = getUsersEvernote(person.getId());
                    com.evernote.auth.EvernoteAuth evernoteAuth = new EvernoteAuth(EVERNOTE_SERVICE, everNote.getAccessToken());
                    NoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = new ClientFactory(evernoteAuth).createNoteStoreClient();

                    NoteSelection noteSelection = this.noteSelectionService.checkIfSelectionValid(groupNoteId, person.getId());

                    if (!(noteSelection == null)) {

                        if (!(noteSelection.getEverNoteGuid() == null)) {
                            Note note = findNoteById(noteSelection.getEverNoteGuid());
                            if ((note != null)) {
                                if(groupNotes.getMnotetag()!=null) {
                                    String c = groupNotes.getMnotetag();
                                    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
                                    Matcher match = pt.matcher(c);
                                    while (match.find()) {
                                        String s = match.group();
                                        c = c.replaceAll("\\" + s, "");
                                    }
                                    note.setTitle(c);
                                }
                                note.setUpdatedIsSet(true);
                                //note.setTitle(groupNotes.getMnotetag());
                                String nBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
                                nBody += "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">";
                                nBody += "<en-note>" + Jsoup.parse(groupNotes.getMnotetext()).text() + "</en-note>";
                                note.setContent(nBody);
                                Note savedNote = noteStoreClient.updateNote(note);
                                if(groupNotes.getTags()!=null) {
                                    String[] tagsList = groupNotes.getTags().split(",");
                                    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    Collections.addAll(stringList,tagsList);
                                    note.setTagNames(stringList);
                                }
                                this.noteSelectionService.updateSelectionWithGuid(groupNoteId, person.getId(), savedNote.getGuid());
                            } else {
                                this.noteSelectionService.deleteSelection(groupNoteId);
                                saveNoteToEvernote(groupNotes, person.getId(), noteStoreClient);
                            }
                        } else {
                            saveNoteToEvernote(groupNotes, person.getId(), noteStoreClient);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you may want to try:

- note.updated is a server side assigned value so you don't need to `note.setUpdatedIsSet(true)`. Also, in general, `***IsSet` is a thrift related flag that you don't want to explicitly set unless you really need to.
- I don't exactly know what `noteSelectionService` does but you are setting tags to `note` while you have `savedNote`. Using `Note#setTagNames` should be good so can you make sure you are calling the `updateNote` API with the right arguments?

Comment: I set the setUpdatedIsSet to true and the time in long, that worked out. Tags are sstill not working with setTagNames. Any ideas? No errors whatsoever. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you call `Note savedNote = noteStoreClient.updateNote(note);` after setting tagNames. Again, I don't know what `noteSelectionService` does so I don't know what's the implications there.